# Receive a POST call with a Readable Stream on Spring Boot and process it as a Stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, axios

I need to post some data on stream, sending it by chunks. Based on [this thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/961), I have a mock Readable Stream that I pass from the frontend with Axios (React).

```
const readableStream = new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
        await wait(1000);
        controller.enqueue('Chunk 1');
        await wait(1000);
        controller.enqueue('Chunk 2');
        controller.close();
    },
});


axios({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/upload',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-Length': size
     },
     data: stream // I also tried sending a Form Data with the stream inside
 })
```

I need to consume this with Spring Boot as a Stream and process the chunks on the fly. The best way I found to do this is:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> upload(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    FileItemIterator iter = new ServletFileUpload().getItemIterator(request);

    FileItemStream item = iter.next(); // Throws NoSuchElementException: null
    InputStream in = item.openStream();

    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // Testing what did I receive
    return new ResponseEntity<>("foo", HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

This code throws NoSuchElementException. I also tried with `@RequestPart MultipartFile file` (for the Form Data method) but it stills don't find `file`.

**Update**

I tried something similar using fetch as http client:

```
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", stream);

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
```

In this case I get the literal `"[object ReadableStream]"`, which is the javascript identifier for the object, not the data.